# MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance is unavailable on MonoTouch?

Tags: xamarin.ios, mapkit

I am trying to convert a Map example from objective-c to MonoTouch but the MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance isn't wrapped in .NET as far as I managed to find.

This issue has been marked as resolved by the MonoTouch team, so where is it? :-)
https://bugzilla.novell.com/show_bug.cgi?id=629743

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's there in MonoTouch 4.

```
using MonoTouch.MapKit;
...
var region = MKCoordinateRegion.FromDistance(center, latmeters, lngmeters);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ah, thanks! Not sure why they changed the method name though, apart from trying to confuse people like me :-)

Comment: I believe it's to make it more .NET-ish :)

Remember to mark as answer.